# how to maintain jquery change preserved on page change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using the below code to slide my navigation menu

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#flipnav").click(function(){
    $("nav").slideToggle("slow");
    }); 
});
```

but on browsing to another page or refresh the navigation is back again. but how to preserve this change so that the navigation remains hidden until the user click to show navigation again and remains same(hidden) even when browses to another page ?

Further

```
if(sessionStorage["navigationMoved"]== "true"){

  $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#flipnav").ready(function(){
    $("nav").slideToggle("slow");
    }); 
}); 

 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#flipnav').toggle(function(){
  $('#content').animate({
   top:"0%"
 });
}, 

function(){
  $('#content').animate({
  top:"2%"
  });     
});
});

}
```

Comment: you mean after first click on "#flipnav" and going to another page "slideToggle" is called automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do a check when the page loads and reset the action. You can use sessionStorage to save information across page reloads or changes.

So

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#flipnav").click(function(){
    $("nav").slideToggle("slow");
    }); 
    sessionStorage["navigationMoved"] = true;
});
```

and then, when you load up a new page, you'll have to have code that says

```
if(sessionStorage["navigationMoved"]){
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#flipnav").click(function(){
       $("nav").slideToggle("slow");
     }); 
     }); 
}
```

When you reload your page it completely rerenders the site based on the HTML/Javascript/CSS provided.  So it doesn't "remember" previous state unless you explicitly save and check for the information

Comment: thank you....but if the user clicks it again to show then what logic should be used for the same slidetoggle to preserve ?

Comment: You can just save false to the session storage then.  Or whatever information you need.  sessionStorage lets you pass an arbitrary object as a value, you just need to give it a string key.  So just pass it whatever info you need to save the state and then recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

You either hardcode the changes in the menu directly in the HTML for each page, or if that's not possible you use cookies or local storage, as HTML is stateless and does'nt remember the changes you've made after a new page loads.

**EDIT:**

Jeezes

You have to store wether or not the menu is visible on every slideToggle, and then check that value on pageload to set the menu accordingly

```
var isSet = localStorage.getItem('nav');
document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].style.display = isSet ? 'block' : 'none';

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flipnav").click(function () {
        $("nav").slideToggle("slow", function() {
            localStorage.setItem('nav', $("nav").is(':visible'));
        });
    });
});
```

I tend to use localStorage, but sessionStorage is part of the same HTML5 web storage API, so you can use that if persistency over just the session is what you're looking for.

For older browsers [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) has a polyfill that falls back to cookies, so you can consistently use the web storage syntax without having to worry about non-supporting browsers.

Comment: @user2205104 You can see my answer for some specific code you can use to implement this with sessionStorage.

Comment: @user2205104 He's helping you for free. An attitude like that isn't going to encourage people to answer your question.

Comment: actually my last account was closed for almost no reason in which i asked ALL genuine questions with people answering genuinely , i wanted to take it professionally but im not allowed to post from that account now so im frustrated :(....if you can help it will be great ?

Comment: @user2205104 I have no idea what happened with the last one, but I'd focus on keeping in mind that nobody here is being paid to help you.  They're doing it because they want to do so.  If people are helpful then thank them, if they're not then maybe thank them anyway.  They're still taking time to try and solve your problem.  As far as helping you further, why don't you post some more code to show what you've tried so far, and we can try to figure out whats not working.

Comment: if(sessionStorage["navigationMoved"]== "true"){
    
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#flipnav").ready(function(){
    $("nav").slideToggle("slow");
    }); 
}); 

 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#flipnav').toggle(function(){
  $('#content').animate({
   top:"0%"
 });
}, 

function(){
  $('#content').animate({
  top:"2%"
  });     
});
});
  
}

Comment: but i want that if a person shows the navigation then it remains shown through the session even when refresh ?

Comment: @user2205104 - you've already accepted an answer, did'nt that work for you ?